# Database Connection Error in Plsek VPS Laravel

Tags: laravel, plesk

`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user_name'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin@gmail.com limit 1) ``

I have added all the required attributes in .env file but I am getting this error.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Wrong password?

Comment: @geertjanknapen I have solved it and you are correct I used " " in all values in .env file.